# Connect Android app data with Website database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I'm building soft keyboard for android and it has settings that I want to upload to users row in my database on my website server and then when user changes the device and signs in, settings are the same. I have worked with SQL before, but I haven't had an experience with connecting android app to my website database. I have found something online but it gives my null result for string example I inserted in my database. Here is the table in my database that I want to run test on:

***name   | detail***

lazar  | firstname

jelic  | lastname

rocky  | balboa

I have php script on my hosted website server named `keyboard.php` and this is how it looks:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

$link= $_GET['link']; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM keyboard WHERE link=" . "'" . $link. "'";
$result =mysql_query($query); 

if($result){
     while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
         echo $row['name'] 
         . " " . $row['link'] 
         . " " . $row['time'];
    }
  }
?>
```

Here is my `SyncDatabse.java`:

```
public class SyncDatabase {
public static String getFromDB(String linkToGetData) throws IOException {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.ecloga.org/keyboard.php?link=" + linkToGetData);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    String theResponse =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    return theResponse;
}
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance. Ask anything you want to know.

Comment: Your string theQuery is "http://www.ecloga.org/keyboard.php?name=rocky". Well if you test this URL, you get nothing which explains the null result

Comment: Do not simply put URL query string parameters (`name` in your case) into an SQL statement. Read up on "SQL injection" to know why you don't want this, never ever. Also, never ever catch `NullPointerException`, simply don't - instead resolve it when it happens or check for `null` at the right place beforehand. Never ever catch an exception and don't log anything about it. You ask on SO why your code is wrong but first you should listen to the Compiler and the Runtime.

Comment: What should I set as theQuery to make my app access the php file on my website or directly to my website database if that is possible? @user3641702

Comment: Ok, i removed `NullPointerException` and I worte a code to check if string is null or empty. What should I do? @Risadinha

Comment: In `keyboard.php` I use $_GET for receiving data.  @SubinThomas

Comment: Try to load your php file from browser and see what is your result . First you make sure your php and db connection is fine, then go to android part.

Comment: Like Subin Thomas explained, first check if you can get the data from the URL you specified. Try to see what goes wrong in your php and db. When you get to the android part, you can use HttpURLConnection to retrieve the data

Comment: Thanks for you comment @SubinThomas. I should thought of that before. You are right. When I run the php script that gets the data from my test table it shows nothing...just blank page.

Comment: OK. So replace --name = \"" . $name . "\ -- with --name = '".$name."'--

Comment: first you go with basic db connections. Then later you can implement security aspects like sql injection and mysqli connections.

Comment: I noticed a few big problems in php script. Here is my improved verison that works: `<?php 
    mysql_connect("db7.cpanelhosting.rs", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
   
    mysql_select_db("jelic98_database") or die(mysql_error()); 
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test where name = 'rocky'";
    $result =mysql_query($query); 
    
    if($result){
         while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
             echo $row['detail'];
        }
      }
 ?> ` Now I can start looking at my java code.

Answer (score 1):

Test this php code because your result is empty:

```
if (isset ($_GET ["name"])){
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET ["name"]);
    $query = htmlentities ($query);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = '$name');
    $result = mysql_query($query);


    $rows = array();

            if (!empty($result)){
                while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        // $rows[] = $r; has the same effect, without the superfluous data attribute
                        $r["Column1"] = $r["Column1"];
                        $r["Column2"] = $r["Column2"]; //You can add many columns like the table have
                        $rows[] = $r;                       
                        //$rows[] = array('Deal' => $r);
                    }

                    echo json_encode($rows);

                }

}
```

Comment: Your php won't return anything, first verify your php code and post the result in the question

Comment: I've changed php script as well as java code. Problem solved, but not using you answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @laky.brat can you please post your solution (both android and php) as an answer. Ive been stuck at the same problem for over a week and still not found anything helpfull. :)

Comment: @edwinj provide your json string and your php code in other question, not ever is the same problem.

Comment: @Santiago dont worry, i found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883596/how-to-send-url-paremeters-to-php-server-and-get-back-response-to-android?noredirect=1#comment53599498_32883596 thanks for the reply anyway :)